# Payment Options in Mobile With Prestashop web service

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I want to make mobile app for `prestashop 1.7` e-commerce site, for that I refereed the process for web service provided by [Prestashop](https://www.prestashop.com/en/).

I reached at how to insert orders via web service, but I didn't get understand how to proceed with checkout process through web service.

Can any one tell me that how to get a payment options and checkout for payment through web service of prestashop?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The payment options in PrestaShop are different. All of them have a separate logic of working and processing of payment.

All the checkout steps in PrestaShop can be handled using the web-services in PrestaShop, but to handle Payment Methods is a very time-consuming task, moreover, you can never test the app with all the payment methods that exist for PrestaShop.

So to solve this problem, we recommend that you show the payment steps inside the mobile app as web view as the steps are shown in PrestaShop store's mobile web-store.

You can take a reference from the following App (it currently support PS 1.6 only):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.velsof.prestashopgenericapp&hl=en

Comment: Is there any sample code available to pass my app to Web-view Payment Support. currently i'm searching api to show list out the available payment method in my ionic app. While I search the solution I have read this reply. could you please help me on this to get he list.